# Presenting error to a user in OS X in Popover View

Tags: error-message, mac-os-x, view

I've been developing applications for iOS for a long time, now I am making application for OS X. My application is an agent. My application is a popover from OS X menu in the top of the screen. I need to present an error to a user. Is there any better way instead of using alert view? Here's my popover:[image]

EDIT: The error is about internet connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel that an error alert is not the best use of the menu-bar popover. Most applications I know of use this mechanism as a menu: The user keeps the icon in the menu bar because it shows some sort of information, and clicks on it to access further information and *actions*.

I think the typical OS X model would work something like this:

**Menu Bar Icon**: has multiple states, to reflect current status. You could have an icon for "Good connection" and another for "connection issues"

**Popover**: The popover, as in the mockup you provided, should activate only when the user clicks the menu bar icon, and should be focused on an action. If you offer a way to resolve the connection, include it here. If that's all the popover includes, make it very small. Otherwise, include other info/actions that are useful to your user.

**OS X Notification**: If a bad connection status is a time-sensitive or very important thing for the user to pay attention to, AND the menu bar icon is not prominent enough a way to communicate the status, use a [notification](http://cdn.osxdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/swipe-to-ignore-software-update.jpg). The notification should also include an action the user can use to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Can you elaborate on why you need to show the user an error-message? Under what circumstances is it, that you think this is a right solution? I'm not saying you are wrong, but I'm curious to the peripherals of this "problem"

Comment: I need to show message that user do not have an internet connection.

Comment: So what's your way to present user an error? I need more beautiful way that alert sheet in popover.

Comment: @NikitaZernov I hope I'm right by understanding that you like the popover better than an actual alertview (OK/Cancel alert). Why not fill that popover with a message and perhaps some image to show there is no active internet connection? [Like this](http://www.geek.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/appstore_no_internet.png).